# Hadamard Representation Of An Entire Function Which Order is 1

Tags: complex-analysis

Hadamard says that the genus of an entire function is less or equal than the order of this function. Nonetheless, i've seen that there is also another theorem:

Every entire function f(z) of order 1 with zeros {z1, z2, z3, . . . } (counted
with multiplicity) has the product representation

[image]

Now I ask, if the genus is less or equal than 1, why, according to this formula, is exactly one (because if it were cero e^z/z_n wouldn't appear).

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

The representation you wrote in general is not unique. If $S=\sum|z_n|^{-1}<\infty$,
the same function can be written as
$$f(z)=e^{A+Cz}\prod_{n=1}^\infty\left(1-\frac{z}{z_n}\right),$$
where $C=B+\sum z_n^{-1}.$

If your function is of order $1$, $S$ may be finite or not, and $C$ may be zero or not. If $S$ is finite, and $C=0$ then your function is actually of genus $0$.